# I don't know how to find coordinate systems for a question.

Tags: computer-science, coordinate-systems, matrix-calculus, computational-geometry, computer-vision

MST is $3 \times 3$ homogeneous matrix that transform points from coordinate system $S$ to coordinate system $T$.

1- What are the coordinates of $P$ in coordinate system $O$?

2- What are the coordinates of $P$ in coordinate system $A$?

3- What are the coordinates of $P$ in coordinate system $B$?

4- What is the matrix of MAB? Please show a bit detail of derivation for this i'd be happy?

[image]

Comment: Surely you’ve been exposed to this at some time previous to two days before your exam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get to $P$ from the origin of $O$ you go $3$ units in the $x$ direction and $1$ unit in the $y$ direction. Therefore the coordinates of $P$ in $O$ are $(3, 1).$

To get to $P$ from the origin of $A$ you go $1$ unit in the $x$ direction and $½$ unit in the $y$ direction. Therefore the coordinates of $P$ in $A$ are $(1, ½).$

To get to $P$ from the origin of $B$ you go $½$ unit in the $x$ direction and $-½$ unit in the $y$ direction. Therefore the coordinates of $P$ in $B$ are $(½, -½).$

I don't know the exact definition of $M_{AB}$ and can therefore not help much with that. I suppose that it contains both a transform of the axis directions and of the origin. But exactly how?

Comment: Let’s represent 2D translation as TR(x,y), rotation as R(θ), scale as S(sx, sy). Please write down the series of transformations produces the reflection of a 2D point about an arbitrary line y = 3x+5? Show the 2D transformation matrix (using homogeneous coordinate system) of this transformation. can you solve this one also